# Setting up the Network using GUI in Freebsd

Tags: php, networking, ip, freebsd

I am using freebsd as a voip server. And Its working perfect after setting the static IP in the /etc/rc.conf file.
Now my question is, What is the best way to make it configure using browser.
For example: If I give one default IP where the user can access the the configuration page and can setup there own IPs based on there requirement. It could be either DHCP or Static IP configuration.

Please let me know if we have any open source project or something related to this.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify, you mean configuring client ip from a server, or you want to let user change the server's ip?

Comment: I want to let user change the server's IP.

Comment: Just out of my head: Install an web server (Apache, for example) and write a CGI script on bash that would prompt user with simple HTML form to enter ip address and then call ifconfig with it. You can substitute bash with PHP if you don't care for overhead.